# Social registration/login

Tags: security, authentication

I'm tryin to implement a social registration/login but i don't know exactly how it works. However, i thought about something but i don't know if it is safe to use or not:

1. Once the user try to register/login with Google for example,
   i'll get the necessary data like email, and the id_Token.
2. In the backend i'll verify if the id_Token is valid.
3. If the token is valid, i'll check if a user exists with the same
   email.
4. If it doesn't exists, an account will be created with that email
   and a random password (only one random password is used for all
   Goole auth users).
5. If it exists, then login with the email and the random password.

I don't know if the idea of random password is safe or not.

Comment: Is this because you can't add an extra API method for logging in with oauth *without* password? The idea of one random password for all google auth users strikes me as an unnecessary risk, your app must store it somewhere and if it leaked, do you have a safeguard in place to prevent it to be used to login directly?

Comment: So it is better to let them login without password once the Id Token from google is valid?

Comment: Yeah, you trust the token right?